# Pygame incorrectly rendering an isometric image

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, isometric

This is my code...

```py
import pygame as pyg
import sys

#Game constants
SCREENSIZE = (1400, 800)
running = True

disp = pyg.display.set_mode(SCREENSIZE)

tilemap = [
    pyg.image.load("Grass.png").convert()
]

for y in range(8):
    for x in range(8):
        disp.blit(tilemap[0], (300+x*32 - y*32, 200+x*16 + y*16))

while running:
    for event in pyg.event.get():
        if event.type == pyg.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    pyg.display.update()
```

This is the result on my computer. I am using Windows 11 with a AMD Rysen 7 5700G with integrated graphics...

[image: Result of code]

This is the asset image I am using to build the isometric world

[image: Source asset]

Why am I getting all those black triangles in my image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`convert_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha) instead of [`convert()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert). `convert` is for fully solid surfaces and discards the alpha information.

<s>`pyg.image.load("Grass.png").convert()`</s>

```
pyg.image.load("Grass.png").convert_alpha()
```

See also [How do I blit a PNG with some transparency onto a surface in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634208/how-do-i-blit-a-png-with-some-transparency-onto-a-surface-in-pygame/64630678#64630678).

Comment: Thanks much! I have a question regarding convert_alpha() though. Does it have the same optimizations as regular convert()? I have read that convert() can increase performance immensely.

Comment: @PythonWarrior Both are for optimized surfaces.